# Customise action bar of tabbed page to put search bar in xamarin.forms (Android).

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I am working in xamarin.forms. I want to put search button with search Entry in the action bar. **I found one link which is perfect for the Content page but In my case, There is a tabbed page and its not working.**

http://blog.xhackers.co/xamarin-forms-contentpage-with-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar/

**can anyone help me to find the solution?**

**I need to implement in Android**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `it's not working`?  What unexpected behaviors are you getting?

Comment: I customize control which is given in link. This link is for ContentPage I made it for tabbedPage and apply same way but tabbed is gone. Second approach, I took 5 contentPage inside one TabbedPage. instead of content page I took SearchPage(Custom control) still not working.

Comment: i directly run the project mention in above link in another PC and emulator SearchView widget not display in action bar.

Comment: I found that this control is not working in nougat OS. Instead of "OnCreateOptionsMenu" on mainActivity we have to use "OnPostCreate" for nougat. I can't able to implement in tabbed page. I put search page between tabbed page. In first and last tabbed page control widget not visible and some tabbed page it display more than one time.